# Amazon SQS as a JMS for caching invalidation

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, microservices

We are trying to use Amazon Simple Queue Service(Amazon SQS) as a JMS provider to invalidate the cache for SDL Web microservices. SDL docs have steps to configure ActiveMQ but not for AmazonSQS.

I am wondering if anyone set it up and point out the documents containing the steps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify to understand correctly.

For content service caching invalidation, you need to use Amazon ActiveMQ, not AmazonSQS.

To setup a scaled-out Content Deployer worker, you could use Apache ActiveMQ or AmazonSQS.

Answer to your question.

For [Amazon MQ Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/amazon-mq-creating-configuring-broker.html#configure-basic-broker-settings-console)- Step 1 Configure Basic Broker Settings refer to amazon documentation.

For example, when using Amazon ActiveMQ, you would set the following properties:

```
<RemoteSynchronization FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="20000" Queuesize="512" ServiceMonitorInterval="10000">
   <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="Tridion">
      <JndiContext>
        <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
        <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="ssl://xxxxxx-1.mq.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:61617?soTimeout=5000"/>
        <Property Name="topic.Tridion" Value="ProdLive"/>
        <Property Name="userName" Value="username"/>
        <Property Name="password" Value="password"/>
        <Property Name="trustAllPackages" Value="true"/>
      </JndiContext>
   </Connector>
</RemoteSynchronization>
```

I hope it helps

Comment: SDL documentation shows that we can use any JMS. So I think Amazon SQS should also be supported.

Comment: KB article link added to 8.5 documentation with comment that AmazonSQS will not work as that doesn't support a one producer to multiple consumer broadcast.  https://gateway.sdl.com/communityknowledge?articleName=000011210