# Amazon MQ to scale Deployer worker

Tags: content-delivery, web8.5, microservices

I am checking if we can use Amazon MQ as a JMS to scale Deployer worker micro service. SDL docs says we can use any JMS like Apache ActiveMQ or Amazon SQS. Does that mean we can also use Amazon MQ? Wondering if anyone tried it before.

Related question: [Amazon SQS as a JMS for caching invalidation](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/amazon-sqs-as-a-jms-for-caching-invalidation) is different than this one. This question was for caching invalidation and not for extending the deployer work service.

Comment: Deployed scaled out deployer workers with Amazon SQS and it works great! Have not tried with Amazon MQ.

Comment: Yeah, SDL docs also confirm that JMS like Apache ActiveMQ and Amazon SQS work for scaling deployer worker. We are thinking, as Amazon MQ is cloud solution for Apache ActiveMQ, it should also support but can't see any reference..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use AmazonMQ for your out-scaled deployer messaging. We used it on one of my recent 8.5 projects and didn't experience any significant issues, once configured.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, although this is the answer of my question but curious if have also tried to use a single instance of Amazon MQ for scaling deployer as well as caching invalidation? Wondering if this is possible?

Comment: Hi Mukesh. I thought that is what your question was about - i.e. scaling the deployer workers, rather than using a JMS for cache invalidation? Yes - you can use AmazonMQ for both.